# A function in pandas or numpy to filter column by list of values that follows it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Given a dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"changes":['increase', 'constant', 'constant', 'constant', 'decline', 'constant', 'constant', 'increase', 'constant', 'constant', 'constant','decline', 'constant', 'constant', 'constant',})
```

**output:**

| changes |
| --- |
| increase |
| constant |
| constant |
| constant |
| decline |
| constant |
| constant |
| increase |
| constant |
| constant |
| constant |
| decline |
| constant |
| constant |
| constant |

The task is to delete the rows with `decline` and the `constant` that comes after it.
I do not want to remove `increase` and the `constant` coming after it.

**The expected output in this case should look like:**

| changes |
| --- |
| increase |
| constant |
| constant |
| constant |
| increase |
| constant |
| constant |
| constant |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"changes":['increase', 'constant', 'constant', 'constant', 'decline', 'constant', 'constant', 'increase', 'constant', 'constant', 'constant','decline', 'constant', 'constant', 'constant']})

### Build group
df['group'] = df['changes'].ne(df['changes'].shift()).cumsum()
df
###
     changes  group
0   increase      1
1   constant      2
2   constant      2
3   constant      2
4    decline      3
5   constant      4
6   constant      4
7   increase      5
8   constant      6
9   constant      6
10  constant      6
11   decline      7
12  constant      8
13  constant      8
14  constant      8
```

Create masks to filter out unwanted data

```
mask_1 = df['changes'].eq('decline') & df['changes'].shift(-1).eq('constant')
mask_2 = df['changes'].eq('constant') & df['changes'].shift().eq('decline')
groups = df.loc[mask_1 | mask_2, 'group']
groups
```

[image]

It indicates `group` `3`,`4`,`7`,`8` should be excluded

Assign filtered data to `result`

```
result = df[~df['group'].isin(groups)].drop(columns=['group'])
result
###
    changes
0  increase
1  constant
2  constant
3  constant
4  increase
5  constant
6  constant
7  constant
```